# A difficulty in understanding a solution of a question on the implicit function theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

The question and its solution are given below:

Find for which points in the $xy-plane$ the system $x = u + v, y= u^2 + v^2, z = u^3 + 2v^3 $ determine $z$ as a differentiable function of $x$ and $y$.

The solution is :

[image]

1-But I can not understand how the solution uses the implicit function theorem ? or may be I do not understand exactly which theorem the solution uses.

2-Also why $2(u^2 + v^2) - (u + v)^2 \geq 0?$

3- why we must have $u,v$ as functions of $x,y$?

Comment: For 2): $2(u^{2}+v^{2})-(u+v)^{2}=(u-v)^{2}$.

Comment: what about the 2 other questions?@KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: The first two equations define $u$ and $v$ implicitly as functions of $x$ and $y$; this makes $z$ a function of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy what is he doing in the part starting with in addition till the end?